# Remove on one specific input its outline and keep only the border

Tags: html, css, outline

I tried to use "outline: 0", but this doesn't change a thing.

```css
#input_field {
  outline: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 2px solid turquoise;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_field">
  <input type="text" name="q" size="50">
</div>
```

I still need outline for other inputs.

UPDATED:

```
.lucky_pos, .button_search_pos{    
    text-align: center;
    padding:1px;
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Since i don't want others to be updated, here is a .css regarding the others. The outline should **only** apply on the #input_field.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I used input.input_field:focus{
    outline-width: 0;
} 
earlier, but this also didn't work

Comment: `#input_field input{ outline: 0; }`

Comment: Tried it just now. Did not work

Comment: so you need rounded border but not the border within it?

Comment: Yes @Manjuboyz, i tried the code here aswell https://codepen.io/pen/ . 
Still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/kszvuyrt/17/) to playaround.

```css
#input_field {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 2px solid turquoise;
  padding: 6px;
}

.OutlineNotNeeded {
  border: none;
}

.OutlineNotNeeded:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_field">
  <input type="text" class="OutlineNotNeeded" name="q" size="50">
</div>
```

Comment: I need the outlines on the other inputs. Ideas how to speficy your code?

Comment: You mean you don't want to use `*` mean you have other `input` types which needs outline? then add class, I will update my code.

Comment: Sure. I don't want to apply this non-outline to .lucky_pos, .button_search_pos >>>
.lucky_pos, .button_search_pos{    
    text-align: center;
    padding:1px;
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
}

Comment: Yep got it! mean you already know I assume, you can have the above mentioned code for  a specific class, so that it has no impact on other `selectors`. PS : I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the outline on the `input` on focus.

```
#input_field > input:focus {
   outline:none;
}
```

To remove the border too (which can trick you because it looks the same as an outline and will always stay there even on focus unless you remove it) you can add:

```
#input_field > input {
   border:none;
}
```

If your trying to see a border only when focusing you can go:

```
#input_field > input {
   border:none;
}

#input_field > input:focus {
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to place a different class or id for the input tag for the outline to be focus/not focus. focus state is an action taken when the input is click.

```
input.showoutline:focus{
 outline: color type size;
} 

input.hideoutline:focus{
 outline: 0;
} 

<input class="showoutline"/> 
<input class="hideoutline"/>
```